# Software engineer vs physics engineer vs computational physics

Tags: education, computational-physics, software, metrology, instrument

Don't know if this question is off topic, but i think it is the best place to get an answer. I am finishing the 3rd year of a degree in physics engineering.

I enjoyed the first year, but in the second year I discovered programming and some subjects started not to appeal me. In this third year i am with the same feelings. Now i have to decide what to do next year. In physics engineer i have two options: metrology or instrumentation.

I would like to have opinions about those four options for the master, if possible including informations on salary and in market need.

Also if it is possible to persue software engineering without the need of 'repeating' 3 years , as i know it is possible to do it in computational physics.

NOTE: if you consider there is a best place to make this question please suggest me

Comment: Only you can know what appeals to you. As for your job prospects with either of these titles... rather bleak, I would say. Employers prefer generalists with experience, when you end your education with something this specialized and without experience... good luck finding a good job.